# Outputting outliers into a vector or dataframe in R

Tags: r, if-statement, boxplot

with the help of the lovely Rui Barradas I was able to cycle through multiple columns and create box plots with labeled outliers. Currently, I am trying to output these outliers into a vector using the following code:

```
ClusterRepVector <- character()
i_num = which(sapply(tpose_genexp, is.numeric)) #
str(tpose_genexp[i_num])
i_num <- i_num[c(1, 4, 5)]


lapply(names(tpose_genexp[i_num]), \(x) {
  bp <- boxplot(tpose_genexp[[x]], 
                horizontal = FALSE, # Horizontal or vertical plot
                lwd = 2, # Lines width
                col = rgb(1, 0, 0, alpha = 0.4), # Color
                main = x,
                notch = TRUE, 
                border = "black",
                outpch = 25,       # Outliers symbol
                outbg = "green",   # Outliers color
                whiskcol = "blue", # Whisker color
                whisklty = 2,      # Whisker line type
                lty = 1 )           # Line type (box and median)
  i_row = which(tpose_genexp[[x]] %in% bp$out)
  labs = if(length(i_row)) {
    tapply(row.names(tpose_genexp)[i_row], bp$out, paste, collapse = ", ")
  } else ""
  text(1.1, unique(bp$out), labels = labs, pos = 4)
outliername = c(row.names(tpose_genexp)[i_row])
ClusterRepVector = c(ClusterRepVector, outliername)
})
```

The problem I am having is that everything I am trying returns and empty vector yet prints out the outliers in the console....so I don't understand why it is not saving it.
[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqLBA.png)

Comment: You cannot assign inside a lapply call like that. You get `ClusterRepVector` in the console because it is the last output of the lapply call. Try to assign you lapply like this `named_lapply <- lapply( ...` and then at the end of the call `return(ClusterRepVector)`. Now your ClusterRepVectors are stored in `named_lapply`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.